# Error when scripting the parameters for executing BigQuery via a Python script

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to adapt the asynch_query.py script found at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-samples-python/tree/master/python/samples for use in executing a query and having the output go to a BigQuery table.  The JSON section of the script as I've created it for seting the parameters is as follows:

```
    job_data = {
    'jobReference': {
            'projectId': project_id,
            'job_id': str(uuid.uuid4())
            },
    'configuration': {
            'query': {
                    'query': queryString,
                    'priority': 'BATCH' if batch else 'INTERACTIVE',
                    'createDisposition': 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
                    'defaultDataset': {
                            'datasetId': 'myDataset'
                            },
                    'destinationTable': {
                            'datasetID': 'myDataset',
                            'projectId': project_id,
                            'tableId': 'testTable'
                            },
                    'tableDefinitions': {
                            '(key)': {
                                    'schema': {
                                        'fields': [
                                        {
                                            'description': 'eventLabel',
                                            'fields': [],
                                            'mode': 'NULLABLE',
                                            'name': 'eventLabel',
                                            'type': 'STRING'
                                        }]
                                    } 
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    }
```

When I run my script I get an error message that a "Required parameter is missing".  I've been through the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query trying to figure out what is missing, but attempts at various configurations have failed.  Can anyone identify what is missing and how I would fix this error?

Comment: In your `destinationTable` object, I think you want to name your key `datasetId` instead of `datasetID`.  I don't know if this will solve the problem, though.

Comment: Also in the `jobReference`, you should specify `jobId` instead of `job_id`.

Comment: Danny, you were correct about the datasetID needing to be changed.  However job_id does need to stay as job_id.  Changing that creates a new error.  At least this got me past the parameter missing error.  On to the next error.  ;-)   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's going on. To insert the results of a query into another table I use this code:

```
def create_table_from_query(connector, query,dest_table):
body = {
    'configuration': {
        'query': {
            'destinationTable': {
                'projectId': your_project_id,
                'tableId': dest_table,
                'datasetId': your_dataset_id
            },
            'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
            'query': query,
        },
    }
}

response = connector.jobs().insert(projectId=self._project_id,
                                        body=body).execute()
wait_job_completion(response['jobReference']['jobId'])

def wait_job_completion(connector, job_id):
    while True:
        response = connector.jobs().get(projectId=self._project_id,
                                             jobId=job_id).execute()
        if response['status']['state'] == 'DONE':
            return
```

where `connector` is `build('bigquery', 'v2', http=authorization)`

Maybe you could start from there and keep adding new fields as you wish (notice that you don't have to define the schema of the table as it's already contained in the results of the query).